# Google Plus Api (Circles) get friend larger image

Tags: android, image, google-plus

Good day.I am fetching the friend list of signed in google plus person,and trying to get the main profile image.I get the main profile image like this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++) {
                                Person eachPerson = loadPeopleResult.getPersonBuffer().get(i);
                                Log.d("fasfafasfsafasfas", "onSuccess: " + eachPerson.getImage().getUrl());
                            }
```

But the issue is that it gives me such a link

```
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GyI_Pgmf5IU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACao/0o3DI0FJL-Y/photo.jpg?sz=50
```

where you can notice at the end of the link that sz=50 meaning it small picture,but how can i get the larger image?That is my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple!
You can just replace last two character to your specific size i.e. replace 50 to 500 
make your Image url like

`https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-GyI_Pgmf5IU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACao/0o3DI0FJL-Y/photo.jpg?sz=500`

Comment: helped and fixed!Thank you

Comment: always wc @JeanAllen